# Need explanation of some magic numbers

Tags: javascript, function, char

i found this piece of code in the internet

```
var b = '12-0-17-2-4-11-14';
var xxx = b.split('-').map(function (x) {
  var x = Number(x); 
  return String.fromCharCode(x < 26 ? 97 + x : 39 + x);
}).join('');
console.log(xxx);
```

being:

```
0 = "a";
b = "1";
c = "2";
d = "3";
```

The output of this code will be 'Marcelo', cause

```
12 = "M", 0 = "a",  17 = "r", 2 = "c", 4 = "e", 11 = "l", 14 = "o";
```

I understand until transform all the strings into numbers, but the rest a im not catching

What the fromCharCode`(x < 26 ? 97 + x : 39 + x)` is doing? This pieace of code is responsible for match the numbers with the alphabet.

Can someone explain me?

Comment: What is /the rest/ you're not understanding?

Comment: i just said.. fromCharCode(x < 26 ? 97 + x : 39 + x)

Comment: If x < 26 do 97 + x.. what 97 means???

Answer (score 2):

That little calculation in `fromCharCode` is used to map a zero-indexed alphabet (`0:a,1:b,...25:z,26:A...`) to their proper Character codes:

```js
var output = '';

for(var i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    output += String.fromCharCode(i < 26 ? 97 + i : 39 + i);
}
alert(output);
```

As you can see here: [image]
Charcodes `65-90` are `A-Z`, `97-122` are `a-z`.

So, the first half of the alphabet (`x < 26`), has `97` added to it's index, while the second half (`x >= 26`), has `65-26` added, which is `39`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x < 26 ? 97 + x : 39 + x)
```

just a calculation for forming alphabets out of the numbers.

if the value of x(i.e each number in the string) is less than 26, thus if can be mapped to alphabet(alphabets are 26 right?), then return the char code for that alphabet, else return the charcode for capital alphabet

Answer (score 0):

It converts a number to its ASCII representation.

The 'A' char has 65 decimal value, the 'a' char has 97 decimal value.

You can see an ASCII table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Fair point, but for this particular case, ASCII is enough(and ASCII is a subset of unicode)